# Vertically Aligning Text & Images not consistent across browsers

Tags: html, google-chrome, alignment

I'm trying to vertically align text and an image element inside a table cell. I am using `align="absmiddle"` and it works in IE, but not in Chrome.

How can I vertically align the text and image in the middle on both Chrome and IE?

Here's the code:

```
<tr>
    <td height="17" bgcolor="#550000">
        <div align="center">
            <strong><font color="#000000" size="3">Text</font></strong>
            <img src="Image.jpg" alt="US Image" width="30" height="15" border="0" align="absmiddle">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8xTta/

Answer (score 0):

using `absmiddle` is not only a [common HTML mistake](http://www.csulb.edu/divisions/students/dss/accessibility/web/webaim-12comm.html), but is also considered bad practice when used this way, i.e. you should always separate styles from content, and use external stylesheets instead of inline styles embedded in the markup.

to solve this and achieve cross browser compatibility, replace the `align:absmiddle;` rule and use `vertical-align: middle;` instead.

here's a nice [reference on vertical alignment](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html) that may be of interest to you.